# Possible to access Chrome Incognito session data?

Tags: adb, chrome-for-android

First post in a fit of desperation on what is probably a lost cause. Would there be any way to recover or view Incognito tabs lost during an automatic app update in the past 24 hours by snooping around Chrome’s local data / session cache / etc.?

Assuming this sort of data isn’t completely nuked on leaving Incognito, I’ve read around some old posts to find [something](https://forums.androidcentral.com/android-5-0-lollipop/470836-chrome-lost-all-my-tabs.html#post5434989) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device) might be possible via ADB shell (which I’ve never used) using `run-as`, `backup` or `push`/`pull` commands, but don’t know if any details of the 80-or-so tabs I’m looking for would even be there in the first place, let alone possible to access, extract and read. Another route that came to mind is tracing web traffic from my phone’s IP via my router, but this seems even less feasible. Frustratingly, Google must know what I typed into its search engine, but whether this is possible to isolate for myself or even Google themselves is anyone’s guess. I’m happy to spend time obsessively trawling through obscure logs as long as it’s theoretically viable.

Running Oreo 8.0.0 on an unrooted LG V30+, Chrome is (now) version 69.0.3497.100.

Many thanks in advance, any kind of help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: And the long answer? Even if it's just "still no", at least it points me in the right direction. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No.

The incognito mode is designed in a way such that no trails shall be left locally, so there should be little to no chance you can pull it from the device.

Maybe you can get *some* information via network data, but that's more complex and not guaranteed.